# Regex to match pattern or match everything else - match precendence issue?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that will use something like this

```
/([;\.])|([\s\S]+)/gi
```

to split this

```
a.b.cad0i2!--as.d;e;f;g00))(
```

into this

```
['a','.','b','.','cad0i2!--as','.','d',';','e',';','f',';','g00))(']
```

ie. Everything in the original string is in the final array, with the input regex simply listing a complex set of potential delimiters and I don't want to repeat the list of delimiters in the regex.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you believe you're going wrong? What is your actual output and the expected one?

Comment: The actual result is `["a.b.cad0i2!--as.d;e;f;g00))("]`. I want it to use the second matching group only if the first matching group doesn't match. Instead it seems to always be taking the second matching group.

Comment: If I use `([;\.])|([a-z0-9!-]+)` I get the result I want, however this isn't generalised enough. I'd also like to use this as an opportunity to understand match order precedence in regex.

I don't understand why `([;\.])|([\s\S]+)` and `([;\.])|([a-z0-9!-]+)` would provide different results in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.match` function.

```
> "a.b.cad0i2!--as.d;e;f;g00))(".match(/[^;.]+|[;.]/g)
[ 'a',
  '.',
  'b',
  '.',
  'cad0i2!--as',
  '.',
  'd',
  ';',
  'e',
  ';',
  'f',
  ';',
  'g00))(' ]
```

`[^;.]+` matches any character but not of `;` or `.` one or more times.

`|` OR,

`[;.]` match `;` or `.`

Comment: I'm already using string.match but thanks for this. Is there anyway to write the regex without referring to the delimiter list twice (`;.`)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
var re = /(?=([.;])(?=[^.;]+))/gi; 
var str = 'a.b.cad0i2!--as.d;e;f;g00))(';
var res = [];
var result = str.split(re);
for (var letter of result) { 
  res.push(letter.replace(/^[.;](?=.+)/, ''));
}
alert(res);
```

Result:

```
a,.,b,.,cad0i2!--as,.,d,;,e,;,f,;,g00))(
```